# Changing the whole column value automatically at 12:00 am on a table of database while working on android app

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, android-studio-3.0

I am making an app and in that i have a table "mydoctor" in which there are two fields no_of_pat and count initially both are same but at the end of day they will differ as i am making changes in count table ...but for the next day i again want the values same for both the attributes.

Initially

```
Ex.   demailid            no_of_pat          count
      lily@gmail.com        15                15
      siri@gmail.com        20                20
```

after the working of my app for whole day long the table becomes
 Ex.

```
          demailid            no_of_pat          count
          lily@gmail.com        15                0
          siri@gmail.com        20                10
```

Now again for another day i want the table as

```
      demailid            no_of_pat          count
      lily@gmail.com        15                15
      siri@gmail.com        20                20
```

demailid is primary key here.
So i am thinking of changing the database values at every 12:00 am how can i do this?
or is there any other approach to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: you could create an `event` in the database to run at a particular time every day

Comment: Don't store the count at all, write the query so that it counts *for* you. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count